# Authorize.net TLS Disablement Notice, Gravity Forms, and Let's Encrypt

Tags: wordpress, ssl, authorize.net, lets-encrypt, gravityforms

I'm a part-time WordPress developer, but have only a bit of knowledge about TLS. I help my friend, who has a very small business where she sells classes online. Her WordPress site uses Gravity Forms to sell classes. We have a SSL through Let's Encrypt and use https.

My friend set up the basics of her Authorize.net account so that she receives money when students register online, through a Gravity Forms/Authorize.net add-on. I have had nothing to do with her Authorize.net account. So when she sent me the Authorize.net email about Disablement for TLS 1.0 and 1.1, I was left in the dark.

We host on a VPS with Dreamhost. I could not find the TLS level anywhere in documentation from DreamHost or Let's Encrypt (or is it Gravity Forms?). I set up an Authorize.net Sandbox account, but have no idea what to do with it, since I know nothing about my friend's dealings with Authorize.net.

Since Let's Encrypt is fairly new, is it safe for me to expect that they will be using TLS 1.2? If not, can you tell me how I can find out if our situation is already using TLS 1.2?

Sincere thanks.

Comment: I understand this isn't the answer you're seeking, but I'm a 12 year dev and I moved away from Authorize.net because it's unusually complicated to work with, and expensive. If you're looking for a simpler solution than you may want to consider PayPal, Stripe or basically anyone but Authorize.net.

Comment: I totally agree. We were using PayPal. Unfortunately, the client got mad at them for some transgression. And she wanted to change. What a big pain!

Answer (score 3):

The TLS connection that Authorize.net is talking about is connections *from* your VPS *to* Authorize.net's API -- that is, when your app is acting as a TLS *client*. So Let's Encrypt doesn't come into this at all, since that's for your TLS *server*.

What you want to know is whether or not the PHP libraries that Gravity Forms for outgoing web requests speak TLS 1.2. (I tried to see what it uses, but since it's commercial software I didn't get anywhere.) My guess is that it uses curl, so provided you have curl > 7.34.0 (when curl started supporting TLS 1.2), and a modern libnss you should be ok. Keep in mind that curl is often built against NSS, not OpenSSL.

I also found [a WordPress plugin which tests PHP for TLS 1.2 compatibility](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tls-1-2-compatibility-test/), precisely to verify the ability to speak to payment gateways. If that plugin gives you a green light then you should be all set for Authorize.net going TLS1.2-only.

Comment: This plugin was great! It gave me the reassurance I needed. Thank you so much for taking the time to comment, and to find this plugin.